# ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FINAL-MESSAGE: server signature is missing

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, supabase, sasl

I'm trying to connect Supabase to my NestJS API. I don't understand this issue :

```
[Nest] 4864  - 10/03/2024 14:46:35   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FINAL-MESSAGE: server signature is missing
```

Supabase  is using PostgreSQL.

I searched for solutions and i'm still struggling ...

Comment: Did you find a solution? Struggling with the same.

Comment: Hello, yes i was using wrong password of the database in my 

`const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: process.env.SUPABASE_DATABASE_TYPE as any,
    host: process.env.SUPABASE_HOST,
    port: process.env.SUPABASE_PORT as any,
    username: process.env.SUPABASE_USERNAME,
password: process.env.SUPABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: "postgres",
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    synchronize: true, // uniquement pour le développement

};`

Comment: Yes i was using wrong password il my `const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {}`